# How to find the OID for particular product?

Tags: snmp, mib

Now, I know the an Avaya switch product "ERS 5510-24T", how can I find the Object identifier for the product without using sysObjectID? Because before use snmpget to get the OID, we need have static list that use to map the OID, and then we know what the product is.

Comment: Send SNMP GET to retrieve the sysObjectID.0 directly from device and you'll find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendors usually have a MIB that identifies its products. For Avaya I found the G3-AVAYA-MIB with some product OIDs, and the Nortel S5-REG-MIB which seems to be more appropriate. If you want to support a vendor, you'll have to search for the OIDs, or ask them.

Comment: It seems we can't get all the OID list just from MIB, the best way is ask the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use sysObjectID for proper network discovery. There is no other way around to identify the device/equipment via SNMP. The target OID is a part **RFC1213 (MIB-II)**

```
Object Name:        sysObjectID
Object ID:      1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0
Object Syntax:      OBJECT IDENTIFIER
Object Access:      read-only
Object Status:      mandatory
Object Description:  The vendor's authoritative identification of the
             network management subsystem contained in the
             entity. This value is allocated within the SMI
             enterprises subtree (1.3.6.1.4.1) and provides an
             easy and unambiguous means for determining `what
             kind of box' is being managed. For example, if
             vendor `Flintstones, Inc.' was assigned the
             subtree 1.3.6.1.4.1.4242, it could assign the
             identifier 1.3.6.1.4.1.4242.1.1 to its `Fred
             Router'.
```

You can use the following command from Net-SNMP package to get the value via SNMPv2C directly from device/equipment:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public device_addr 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. GET `sysObjectId.0` (`1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0`)

From that, you get what looks like on OID.  The sixth (zero based!) element of that is the enterprise id.

2. Now you can zero in on the model, firmware, serial number, etc. of the device.

I use a map from enterprise Id to a collection of OIDs yanked from MIBs for this and I just keep tossing OIDs at the device until it likes one of them.

For example, if I know it's ZyXEL and I want to know the serial number I try these until one hits.

```
("ZyXEL Communications Corp.",
  Seq(".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.15.3.82.2.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.55.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.18.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.19.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.16.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.15.3.1.12.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.59.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.60.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.56.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.21.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.27.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.73.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.53.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.23.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.72.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.12.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.20.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.68.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.12.47.1.10.0",
    ".1.3.6.1.4.1.890.1.5.8.46.1.10.0")),
```

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned OID is `SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0`, with numric value `.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0`

Reference [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3418#page-2)

---

Exmaple using MIB name:

`snmpget -v2c -c public rb750 SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 -On`

Output

`.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: Some device`

---

Exmaple using OID:

`snmpget -v2c -c public rb750  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0`

Output

`SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Some device`